# How to generate synthetic data within a given range using sklearn.datasets.make_classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I want to create synthetic data for a classification problem. I'm using `make_classification` method of `sklearn.datasets`.
I want the data to be in a specific range, let's say `[80, 155]`, But it is generating negative numbers.

I've tried lots of combinations of `scale` and `class_sep` parameters but got no desired output.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
weight = [0.2, 0.37, 0.21, 0.04, 0.11, 0.05, 0.02]

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=3,
            n_informative=3, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, 
            n_classes=7, n_clusters_per_class=1, weights=weight,
            class_sep=1,shuffle=True, random_state=41, scale= 1)

pd.DataFrame(X).describe()
```

### Output

[image]

The output should be in a specific range, but it is picking out random values with standard deviation of around 1.33.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `MinMaxScaler` (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)).

Just run:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(80, 155))
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
y = scaler.fit_transform(y)
```

Note that this scaler will trained once for X and one for y.